# Is it possible to configure reducers to correspond to local HBase regions?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to use reducers to load data to HBase. I'm using `TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob` method to configure the job and pass `HRegionPartitioner` class as a partitioner. But the reducers created this way don't consider data locality. Is it possible to configure the job in such a way that each reducer corresponds to number of HBase regions that are local to the machine it's running on?

Comment: If i read this correctly you want the Reducer to run on the node on which HBase region sits? Just a doubt, since all records go to WAL first does it really matter? Are you not always interacting with the Master?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I did't realize that WAL is located in HDFS and not on the local filesystem. So do you suggest that locality makes absolutely no difference when putting to HBase?

Comment: Yes that is what i think would be the case. Of course just throught of another scenario: HBase Bulk Load. In Bulk load we create the HFiles and then load them. In this case you could control the locality of the HFiles. Bulk load does not go through the WAL.

Comment: I know about bulkload, but as I understand it's recommended to use bulkload only if the amount of loaded data is rather big, otherwise many small bulkloads would cause waste of regionserver resources.

Comment: Yep bulk load is recommended only for large data volumes.